# Call a function when the 'done' button is pressed on the keyboard in Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova app running on iOS.  I've implemented a search box with this html:

```
<form>
  <input type="search" class="historySearchTextbox" id="myFilter" placeholder="Search" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off">
</form>
```

This works fine and gives me a 'Go' button instead of return on the popup keyboard.  I can capture taps on the Go button with this javascript:

```
$('#myFilter').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var theEvent = e || window.event,
        keyPressed = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    if (keyPressed === 13) {
        filter();
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
    return true;
});
```

But I still have the 'done' button to deal with on the keyboard.  I believe there is no keycode that I can use, and my own testing agrees.  Based on reading answers on stack overflow, the best I can do is detect when the keyboard goes away.  I'm using this javascript:

```
$("#myFilter").bind('blur', function (event) {
    window.alert("blur");
});
```

This works but I'd rather have a direct way of detecting a 'done' key tap.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Jon

Comment: What I do is to listen to put the field on a form, and when you push go the submit event is called

Answer (score -7):

The done key is the same as the enter key. So you can listen to a keypress event. I'm writing this using jQuery and i use it in coffee script so I'm trying to convert it back to js in my head. Sorry if there is an error.

```
$('someElem').bind("keypress", function(e){
// enter key code is 13
if(e.which === 13){
    console.log("user pressed done");
} 
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your quick response.  I just tried it though and this does not fire when I hit the 'done' button.  Also, I should have mentioned that I want the Go button snd the done button to do different things.

Comment: This is definitely not true, this answer should be deleted